# Are has_and_belongs_to_many reflections gone in Rails 4.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I don't understand why they have changed this behavior so heavily and how to get the old results back. Some of my abstract code depends on the `reflections` method.

In 4.0.4 this code returned something you would expect:

```
User.reflections.each_pair { |a, x| puts [a, x.macro].join(' => ') }

games => has_many
posts => has_many
players => has_many
teams => has_and_belongs_to_many
roles => has_and_belongs_to_many
```

In 4.1.0 the same database and model returns this:

```
User.reflections.each_pair { |a, x| puts [a, x.macro].join(' => ') }

games => has_many
posts => has_many
players => has_many
users_teams => has_many
teams => has_many
users_roles => has_many
roles => has_many
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic

  has_many :games
  has_many :posts
  has_many :players
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

end
```

Comment: I think you found the info you were looking for at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14682 Probably you should add an answer here too based on that info.

Comment: @dknight Will do, 4.1.1 still has this bug, i guess we need to wait for 4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This unexpected behavior happened in rails `4.1.0` and `4.1.1`, since `4.1.2` `reflections` is public api that returns values you would expect.

More on my problem can be found in the [github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14682) i've opend